# CS0103: The name does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, web-services, webforms

Here is the main form where I have to take user inputs. I have used Design option to create the form in visual studio.

**WebForm1.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="ArthmeticClient.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            
            <br />
            Enter Value 1:
            <input id="Text1" type="text" /><br />
            <br />
            Enter Value 2:
            <input id="Text2" type="text" /><br />
            <br />
            Resul:
            <input id="Text3" type="text" /><br />
            <br />
            <input id="Button1" type="button" value="Addition" />
            <input id="Button2" type="button" value="Multiplication" /><br />
            <br />
            
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I have used the same id for the input tag but still it cannot find the content.

**WebForm1.aspx.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace ArthmeticClient
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ServiceReference1.IService1 ob = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
            int num1 = int.Parse(Text1.Text);
            int num2 = int.Parse(Text2.Text);
            
            Text3.Text = Convert.ToString(ob.Sum(num1, num2));
        }

        protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ServiceReference1.IService1 ob = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
            int num1 = int.Parse(Text1.Text);
            int num2 = int.Parse(Text2.Text);

            Text3.Text = Convert.ToString(ob.Multiply(num1, num2));
        }
    }
}
```

I have to just a small option, I have created simple form, I dont think there a problem with the id I have given. but it is still showing this error. Idk what is wrong.
Can anybody help...

Comment: You haven't shown the full error message, so we can't really help, but it should tell you exactly what bit of code is going wrong.

Comment: Though looking at your code, this appears to be WebForms and none of your controls have the `runat="server"` attribute, so perhaps that is the problem. That also suggests that you need to run through some basic WebForms tutorials. However, if you are learning a new technology, I would avoid WebForms since it is now mostly considered a legacy thing, go learn ASP.NET Core MVC instead.